# How to align two python arrays with the same values but nans in one

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, nan

I have two identical arrays (well, pandas dataframe with indexes, but I think the example will stay the same with arrays), but one has nans interspersed.

for example:

`a=[1,2,3,np.nan,4,5,np.nan,6,np.nan,7,np.nan,8,np.nan,9,10]`

and

`b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

is there an easy (vectorised) way to reshape `b` so it effectively turns into `a` - with nans in the same place as `a`?

I know that could just loop through and if nan, add a nan to the other. But I want a more elegant solution than that.
thanks!

Edit. For reference, this is for an issue with `statsmodels.api` where `.get_prediction()` returns confidence interval data and estimate, but strips out the nans (indexes to put back together later), and `.predict()` gives the esimate with the true indexes including nan. Need to consoldate these together to get the confidence interval for new estimates.

If anyone is looking for an answer to the difference in `.get_prediction` between statsmodels and statsmodels.api, where nans are removed by the function. The following code works (but needs to be wrapped into pandas). Sorry if this question was written poorly. Hope to help people because there is no information about this.

This is the answer to the question as is. I don't understand why it was closed. This is the best solution.

```
def nan_merge(a,b):
    indices = np.where(np.isnan(a))[0]
    ans = np.insert(arr=b, obj=indices-list(range(len(indices))), values=np.nan)
    return ans

def test_nan_merge():
    a = np.array([1,2,3,np.nan,4,5,np.nan,6,np.nan,7,np.nan,8,np.nan,9,10])        
    b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]).astype(float)
    assert (nan_merge(a,b)==a).any()
```

Fully wrapped code for pandas could be something like this. Not as elegant as the answer provided below, but will deal with duplicate numbers which isn't solved by the pandas merge solution.

```
def get_true_indexes(data,model):
    '''
    Predict returns all indexes
    Get prediction removes nans so destroys indexing.
    But provides Low and high CI.
    So lets merge them. 
    '''
    
    def nan_merge(a,b):        
        indices = np.where(np.isnan(a))[0]
        ans = np.insert(arr=b, obj=indices-list(range(len(indices))), values=np.nan)
        return ans
    
    def test_nan_merge():
         
        a=np.array([1,2,3,np.nan,4,5,np.nan,6,np.nan,7,np.nan,8,np.nan,9,10])
        b=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]).astype(float)
        assert (nan_merge(a,b)==a).any()
        
    
    df1=model.predict(data).copy(deep=True)
    df1.name='predict'
    df1=df1.to_frame()
    df1=df1.reset_index()
    
    df2= model.get_prediction(data).summary_frame()
   
    real=df1['predict'].values
    mea=df2['mean'].values
    upp=df2['obs_ci_upper'].values
    low=df2['obs_ci_lower'].values
    
    if len(real)!=len(mea):
        mea = nan_merge(real,mea)
        upp= nan_merge(real,upp)
        low= nan_merge(real,low)
    
    ans=pd.DataFrame({'mean':mea,'obs_ci_upper':upp,'obs_ci_lower':low},index=df1['index'].to_list())
               
    return ans
```

Comment: will `b` always have the same elements as in `a`, such as 1, 2, 3, 4.. as in your example?

Comment: Yes they will be identical order just interspersed with nans.

Comment: uh.... `b=a`? ... sounds like XY problem...

Comment: Then why wouldn't you just use `a`? If the goal is to make `b == a`.

Comment: b has some additional data (in a pandas dataframe) in this case that I require to get out

Comment: Scaling up a single array `b` and scaling up a column in a dataframe to match `a` are _very_ different problems.

Comment: I just need the matching indexes it shouldn't matter the format of them.

Comment: please give a more appropriate example and expected output then (for eg `b` with additional data).

Answer (score 1):

If the values in a and b are unique, you can merge and sort on the original index of b's dataframe to get what you want.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b':['A', np.nan, 'B', np.nan, 'C', 'D'], 'other column':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
df2 = df2.reset_index()

df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='a', right_on='b', how='outer')
df3 = df3.sort_values(by='index')
```

to get df3:

```
     a  index    b  other column
0    A      0    A             1
4  NaN      1  NaN             2
1    B      2    B             3
5  NaN      3  NaN             4
2    C      4    C             5
3    D      5    D             6
```

Comment: This works well. Thanks for the solution. However yes it appears that I have some rare duplicates. I handle this by `df3=df3.drop('index',axis=1)` and `df3=df3[(~df3.duplicated()) | (df3['mean'].isnull())]` but still not a perfect solution. 

I was going to mark you as correct, however due to this limitation I might wait a little longer and see if it is possible to build on this solution.